# How to make circular indicators with recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I want to show 4 selected indicators on the TOP  at the same time with the recycler view. I am attaching a screenshot of what I want to achieve.

[image: I am attaching a screenshot of what I want to achieve.]

This is the code I have done so far.

Adapter code:

```
public class MyDotsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyDotsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Dots[] listdata;

public MyDotsAdapter(Dots[] listdata) {
    this.listdata = listdata;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    View listItem = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dots_item, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(listItem);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (listdata[position].isSelected()) {
        holder.dot_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.selected_circle);
    } else {
        holder.dot_imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.unselected_circle);
    }
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listdata.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public ImageView dot_imageView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        dot_imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.dot_imageView);
    }
}
```

}

My Main Activity code:

```
Dots[] dotList = new Dots[]{
            new Dots(true),
            new Dots(true),
            new Dots(true),
            new Dots(true),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
            new Dots(false),
    };

    MyDotsAdapter myDotsAdapter = new MyDotsAdapter(dotList);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this,LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL,false);
    dot_recyclerview.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    dot_recyclerview.setAdapter(myDotsAdapter);

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING) {
                //Dragging
            } else if (newState == RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
                int position = manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                Log.e("position", String.valueOf(position));
                Log.e("Size", String.valueOf(myListData.length));
                if (position + 4 == myListData.length) {
                    dot_recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(position + 4);
                    updateModel(position);
                    myDotsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    dot_recyclerview.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
                    updateModel(position);
                    myDotsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        }
    });

public void updateModel(int position) {

    for (Dots dots : dotList) {
        dots.setSelected(false);
    }
    for (int i = position; i < position + 4; i++) {
        dotList[i].setSelected(true);
    }
}
```

This is the screenshot of what I have achieved so far. I want to add small unselected circles before and after of selected circles as I am moving forward. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: We need to see some code of what you have tried

Comment: @KristyWelsh I have updated the question, please check now.